# How to Select / Deselect All Checkboxes using jQuery with a one Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, checkbox

I would like to to use a single button click to toggle between selecting all check boxes within a particular div/table and deselecting all check boxes. In addition i wanted the link/or button to change names to 'Select All' & ' deselect All'. I've seen similar answers using check boxes or two different button clicks but nothing for this. I would to keep it simple and short using jquery.

HTML

```html
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="first">
<h1>Check & Uncheck All Options</h1>
<p>Check & Uncheck All Options by Button</p>
<input id="checkAll" type="button" value="Check/Uncheck All ">
<div class="button">
<input class="first" id="Item 1" name="option1" type="checkbox">
<label class="label1" for="Item 1">Item 1</label>
<input class="first" id="Item 2" name="option1" type="checkbox">
<label class="label1" for="Item 2">Item 2</label>
<input class="first" id="Item 3" name="option1" type="checkbox">
<label class="label1" for="Item 3">Item 3</label>
<input class="first" id="Item 4" name="option1" type="checkbox">
<label class="label1" for="Item 4">Item 4</label>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about like this:

```js
$(function() {
  
  $(document).on('click', '#checkAll', function() {
  
    if ($(this).val() == 'Check All') {
      $('.button input').prop('checked', true);
      $(this).val('Uncheck All');
    } else {
      $('.button input').prop('checked', false);
      $(this).val('Check All');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="first">
      <h1>Check & Uncheck All Options</h1>
      <p>Check & Uncheck All Options by Button</p>
      <input id="checkAll" type="button" value="Check All">
      <div class="button">
        <input class="first" id="Item 1" name="option1" type="checkbox">
        <label class="label1" for="Item 1">Item 1</label>
        <input class="first" id="Item 2" name="option1" type="checkbox">
        <label class="label1" for="Item 2">Item 2</label>
        <input class="first" id="Item 3" name="option1" type="checkbox">
        <label class="label1" for="Item 3">Item 3</label>
        <input class="first" id="Item 4" name="option1" type="checkbox">
        <label class="label1" for="Item 4">Item 4</label>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('#checkAll').click(function(){
    if($( 'input[name="option1"]:checked' ).length>0){//any one is checked
        $('.button input').prop('checked', false);
    }
    else{
        $('.button input').prop('checked', true);
    }
    })


<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="first">
      <h1>Check & Uncheck All Options</h1>
      <p>Check & Uncheck All Options by Button</p>
      <input id="checkAll" type="button" value="Check All">
      <div class="button">
        <input class="first" id="Item 1" name="option1" type="checkbox">
        <label class="label1" for="Item 1">Item 1</label>
        <input class="first" id="Item 2" name="option1" type="checkbox">
        <label class="label1" for="Item 2">Item 2</label>
        <input class="first" id="Item 3" name="option1" type="checkbox">
        <label class="label1" for="Item 3">Item 3</label>
        <input class="first" id="Item 4" name="option1" type="checkbox">
        <label class="label1" for="Item 4">Item 4</label>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a class that maintains the state of the checkboxes. use that to toggle the `checked` property of the checkboxes.

```
var $checkboxes = $('.first');
var $selectAllCheckbox = $('#checkAll');

$selectAllCheckbox.on('click', function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  var allChecked = true;

  if ($this.hasClass('checked-all')) {
    $this.removeClass('checked-all');
    allChecked = false;
  } else {
    $this.addClass('checked-all');
  }

  $checkboxes.prop('checked', allChecked);
});

// Maintain the state if the checkbox is
// checked individually
$('.first').on('change', function() {
    var isChecked = true;
    $.each($checkboxes, function(i, checkbox) {
        if(!$(checkbox).is(':checked')) {
           isChecked = false; 
        }
    });

     isChecked ? $selectAllCheckbox.addClass('checked-all') 
                : $selectAllCheckbox.removeClass('checked-all');
});
```

**[jSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tte67cr/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e)
    {
        jQuery(".check_all").click(function()
        {
           jQuery(".all_checked").attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false);
        })
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check_all"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="all_checked"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="all_checked"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="all_checked"/>
```

Comment: Always, always post explanations with your answers.  Code-only posts are low-quality because they do very little to educate readers.